# Oauth: Redirect url has https, but original website is on http

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0

Here is the issue:

Website(Some clients login as http and some as https) = **http**://www.example.com

Dropbox redirect needs to be **https**://www.example.com (Dropbox does not allow redirect urls to be **http**)

If my website is **https**://www.example.com it all works great. But for some clients it is http. I am okay with redirect = https, but it should come back to my http page after user logs in via popup window.

Any suggestions how to do this?

Here is my code:

```
this._oauthSignIn(url, dropboxRedirect).then(
    lang.hitch(this, function (oauthSignInUrl) {
      this._getTokenValue(oauthSignInUrl, 'access_token').then(
        lang.hitch(this, function (accessToken) {
          dfd.resolve(accessToken);
        })
      );
    })
  );

_oauthSignIn: function (url, redirect_uri) {
  var dfd = new Deferred();
  var win = window.open(url, "_blank", 'width=800, height=600');
  win.focus();
  var pollTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
    try {
      if (win.document.URL.indexOf(redirect_uri) != -1) {
        window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
        win.close();
        dfd.resolve(win.document.URL);
      }
    } catch(e) {
    }
  },100);
  return dfd;
},

_getTokenValue: function (url, name) {
  var dfd = new Deferred();
  name = name.replace(/[[]/,"\[").replace(/[]]/,"\]");
  var regexS = "[\?&#]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( url );
  if( results == null )
      dfd.resolve("");
  else
      dfd.resolve(results[1]);
  return dfd;
},
```

Comment: There is a reason why Dropbox does not allow redirect over http. If I'm reading the code correctly, this is the implicit grant flow. If the redirect is http, then the token is sent in cleartext. OAuth 2.0 requires https in order to be secure.

Comment: Redirect url being https is okay. But the issue is, how do I send the token from the https redirect url(popup) to my original webpage which is http.

Comment: You mustn't send the token over http, there are no ways around it.

Comment: You can have a look at, for instance, https://letsencrypt.org to set up https for your site.

Comment: Also have this issue with subdomains: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46943282/subdomains-oauth2-and-postmessage . I think solving subdomains will also solve http vs https issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this to work, so posting the workaround for this use case.

Using this example:
Customer page: www.abc.example.com/something.html

Oauth redirect page = www.example.com/oauthTest.html

Hidden Iframe = www.example.com/iframe.html

Create a hidden iframe on the customer page. This hidden iframe when called, starts popup.
When user clicks on login with dropbox, the hidden iframe opens the oauth popup. Since hidden iframe and oauth popup are on same domain this works fine, and they can cross communicate.
Once you get token on the hidden iframe, send it to customer page via postmessage.
Now you have the token to work with in your application.
Add protection around iframe, so only your application can call it.